# Google Sheets – Dynamic Calculation of Data Validation

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates, data-validation, google-sheets-data-validation

My use case is to select between two times within a single day.

- The first cell ("from" time) has `list of items` data validation set up, where the options are as follows:

  `12:00 am,1:00 am,2:00 am,3:00 am,4:00 am,5:00 am,6:00 am,7:00 am,8:00 am,9:00 am,10:00 am,11:00 am,12:00 pm,1:00 pm,2:00 pm,3:00 pm,4:00 pm,5:00 pm,6:00 pm,7:00 pm,8:00 pm,9:00 pm,10:00 pm,11:00 pm`
- The second cell ("to" time) currently has the same `list of items` data validation set up

However, it's not realistic for the user to select a "to" time that is before the "from" time. Therefore, I wonder is it possible to code the data validation for the "from" time to consider the "to" time that they've previously selected?

For example: if the user selects 4:00pm as the "from" time, they can only select from `5:00 pm,6:00 pm,7:00 pm,8:00 pm,9:00 pm,10:00 pm,11:00 pm` for the "to" time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: list]

I used numbers in this example.
In column C I have inserted the list we need and, in column D, I have inserted a filter with:

```
=arrayformula( ifna ( filter ( C2:C, C2:C > A2 ),""))
```

Finally, I validated cell B2 with

```
=$D$2:$D
```

as "list by range"

BTW: [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IUdyJQILkhXse0LJNhGM4mKrGlmC0bP_b1JrHhlNUEk/edit?usp=sharing) a sheet based on hours

Comment: Thanks, Daniele! Is there any way to remove seconds from the Data Validation list? 7:00am looks much better than 07:00:00